# Domain is not working without port number

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, port

I deployed my application in AWS ec2 instance and it is working well with instances's IP address. Instead of using IP address I bought a domain from godaddy and connected to my ec2 instance with load balancer and target group. And also generated a SSL certificate for https. Now my domain http://example.com is working fine but while I changed http to https it is working with port number like https://example.com:5005

How can I remove that port number in url? Do I need to add anything in target group or load balancer?? Can someone help me to resolve this.

thanks in advance!

Comment: in your load balancer, create a listener for 443, mapping to instance's 5005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide the port number in the URL , the standard port for the protocol is used, which in your case will be 443 for https.

You need to create a standard HTTPS listener on your load balancer, which can forward the traffic recevied on 443 to your instance(s) port 5005 as part of the target group.